# Opentest on Linux

Tags: command-line

I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and I want to get Opentest on my PC. I cannot connect to the site in the instructions of the installation "http://localhost:3000". When I try to connect to the site it says "localhost refused to connect". What does that mean and how can I fix that?

Tutorial Link: https://getopentest.org/docs/installation.html

After typing `opentest` into the terminal, it gave me an error:

```
Not enough non-option arguments: got 0, need at least 1
```

Comment: `http://localhost:3000` is where one might find Opentest after the server was installed, configured, and started.

Comment: @waltinator I installed it and set up the configs, but no new results.